# what kind and how much logic to store in django views

Tags: django, django-views

My django views are getting rather large.  I am wondering how much and what kind of logic is recommended for a django view.

When a view goes beyond the recommended scope, is there a recommended file to use to abstract out logic like data controller or view controller?

Answer (score 0):

Django has its own interpretation of MVC:

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/faq/general/#django-appears-to-be-a-mvc-framework-but-you-call-the-controller-the-view-and-the-view-the-template-how-come-you-don-t-use-the-standard-names

In that context, I recomment that you put very little logic in your views. Views are the plumbing of you code. They are statements like: "Take this data from that model and put it in this template using that context."

The logic where the magic happens should go into the models in form of methods and computed properties.

If you have a specific code example of your views, I can try to give you more concrete advice.

Comment: A lot of logic applies to multiple models. In that case, where do you put those functions?

Comment: @Atma Maybe these models can inherit from a common ancestor. Make sure to tell Django that this is an abstract ancestor, otherwise it will mess with your performance: https://jacobian.org/writing/concrete-inheritance/

Comment: @Atma you can also keep code in other module files like with any python project. Aside from the models.py, and views.py, I often keep a tasks.py and other modules. It's just Python, after all.

Comment: Thanks for that Konstantin.  Can you post an example of a view and then what you abstract out to a model.  Thanks.

Comment: @Atma I think it is better if you post some code which you don't know where to put and I tell you where to put it.